# Dual monitor setup with Intel NUC7i5DKNE and CentOS 7

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, centos, xorg

I'm trying to configure dual monitor setup with my Intel NUC7i5DKNE and CentOS 7.

The NUC have two HDMI outputs and according to the manual supporting up to 2 screens with 4K.

In any case, I don't see the second monitor in settings and `xrandr -q` showing one of the screens is disconnected.

Should I modify/create `xorg.conf` file?

Comment: Why should you? You're trying to your 2nd monitor to work and you shouldn't ask if that solution works. See [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira great answer.
I want to know how can I enable second monitor if it doesn't appear in settings? As this is not a laptop, there is no Switch screen button (like Fn+F8 on Asus)

Comment: did you get this to work?